# Is there a way to sort a parent record by the earliest date associated with its child records?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables, an invoices table and a workdays table.  Invoices has many workdays.

The workday schema has:

invoice_id: integer, date: date

And let's say the invoices schema just has an id in the table for now.

In the view of my application, I would like to print out all the invoices preloaded with all the workdays.  For each invoice, child workdays should be sorted by date.  And even though there is no date field on the invoice, I'm wondering is it possible to sort the invoices by the earliest date amongst all it's corresponding children workdays?

The goal is to be able to produce a view that would look something like:

```
Invoice date range: Jan 02, 2019 - Jan 03, 2019
Workdays: 
Jan 02, 2019
Jan 03, 2019

Invoice date range: Jan 05, 2019 - Jan 06, 2019
Workdays:
Jan 05, 2019
Jan 06, 2019
```

I'm using a query like this: select * from invoice inner join workdays on workdays.invoice_id = invoice.id order by workdays.date

But it's possible to have invoices out of order because the order on the invoices is not specified.  I don't know of any other way to specify the sort order on the invoice without caching the earliest workday.date into the parent (invoice) on a new column and then sorting by that extra column.

Update: I use postgres and mysql.  By 'view' I do not mean database (materialized) view, I meant model, view, controller, view layer.

Comment: You have to use `exists`  subquery, with `With` if you reuse table, to search for `max()` date and also `left` for things like "even though there is no date field on the invoice". Without datas, examples and so on it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Your desired output is impossible with a view, as each row contains a different number of columns. In a relational database a table, view or the result of a SELECT statement always has the same number of columns in every row. And the data type of that column is fixed for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
select 
    i.id, i.comment,
    min(wd.date) as invoice_range_from, max(wd.date) as invoice_range_to
from invoice i
left join workdays wd on i.id = wd.invoice_id
group by i.id
order by min(wd.date), max(wd.date)
```

If you want to retrieve your parent-children in one server round-trip, use your RDBMS's JSON or XML capability, especially if your client app will consume JSON anyway, you can use the following. e.g.,

Live test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0b1ce002c4380a3542387209c3c43fae

```
select 
    i.id, i.comment,
    min(wd.date) as invoice_from, max(wd.date) as invoice_to,
    json_agg(json_build_object('date', wd.date)) as workdays_data
from invoice i
left join workdays wd on i.id = wd.invoice_id
group by i.id
order by min(wd.date), max(wd.date)
```

Output:

```
id  comment invoice_from    invoice_to  workdays_data
1   Hello   2019-01-02      2019-01-03  [{"date" : "2019-01-02"}, {"date" : "2019-01-03"}]
2   Hola    2019-01-05      2019-01-06  [{"date" : "2019-01-05"}, {"date" : "2019-01-06"}]
```

Otherwise, you would have to use your ORM's batching capability. If don't have a capable ORM, you need to manually make your query minimize the server roundtrips.

If want to go all out with your RDBMS's JSON capability to render tree-like data in one go though, you can :)

Live test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ed3105719ed033ba568e01b3d97c234

```
with a as 
(
    select 
        i.id, i.comment,
        min(wd.date) as invoice_range_from, max(wd.date) as invoice_range_to,
        json_agg(json_build_object('date', wd.date)) as workdays_data
    from invoice i
    left join workdays wd on i.id = wd.invoice_id
    group by i.id
    order by min(wd.date), max(wd.date)
)
select json_agg(a.*) from a;
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "comment": "Hello",
        "invoice_range_from": "2019-01-02",
        "invoice_range_to": "2019-01-03",
        "workdays_data": [
            {
                "date": "2019-01-02"
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-01-03"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "comment": "Hola",
        "invoice_range_from": "2019-01-05",
        "invoice_range_to": "2019-01-06",
        "workdays_data": [
            {
                "date": "2019-01-05"
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-01-06"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Schema:

```
create table invoice
(
  id int primary key,
  comment text not null
);


create table workdays
(
  invoice_id int not null references invoice(id),
  id int not null generated by default as identity primary key,
  date date not null
);


insert into invoice(id, comment) values
(1, 'Hello'),
(2, 'Hola');

insert into workdays(invoice_id, date) values
(1, '2019-1-2'),
(1, '2019-1-3'),
(2, '2019-1-5'),
(2, '2019-1-6');
```